# Echoing HTML or generate it through JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a functional project that is basically a database table editor. You load a table and you can get the rows info, edit it, add, delete, add child rows, etc.

I am rewriting the entire thing because it is very unorganized. I am attempting to create a class based system (yes I had 0 classes). This is my first class based project and, that being another issue, I would like to know the best (performance, maintainability, ease-of-writing) way to generate dynamic HTML. I use Javascript and PHP

Really the options, when outputting dynamic HTML are:

1. Echo it directly, or JSON encoded, from a PHP function or class
2. Build it from Javascript and append things to the document

I can either make a request from JS and append the data directly from PHP, or I can just get back raw data from PHP (database) and build it using JS. I really don't know what the optimal way to go here is. Currently I am raw echoing my tables and editing forms, and it works, but it's a mess.

Comment: It's best to avoid mixing code and generating html in js whenever possible.

Comment: Check out ng-grid. http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Comment: @Chris I doubt ng-grid would work without angular ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide data (via php) to your WebApp, you should build a REST-Service (in php simply a new php file), perform the database requests in the php file and give the data as JSON String back to the client.

1. So in your client App you can make a AJAX request to get your data and parse the responseText with JSON.parse(responsetext) to a javascript object. Now you can access the data in the object.
2. For building webapps with databindings you should have a look on [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). Angular is using a very interesting model to build nice Apps without thinking to much about DOM.

Best regards

Dustin

P.S.: You should also have a look on [nodeJS](http://nodejs.org/). It's much faster than php and you can code javascript on client and serverside. Furthermore it has a bunch of features like Socket.IO where php cannot hold.